# AEM WKND tutorial component basics eclipse not recognizing jcr properties

Tags: eclipse, maven, aem

I am doing the WKND tutorial and in the component basics section https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-wknd-tutorial-develop/component-basics.html
the tutorial jumps into loading the project in eclipse and it seems that they have all the tools in place. I imported the project as an maven project and have the aem tools built in but I do not see the create node option when I try to create something under ui.app
[image]
I cannot see any jce properties populate anywhere
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the `Content Module` option inside `Project Faces` as follow:

[image]

Then restart the IDE and you'll be available to create a new `Node`.

[image]

Comment: Didn't do anything

Comment: Do you have installed the AEM and Sling plugins? Did you restart the IDE? That works for me.